# Google PlayStore - App update rejected even after updating the DataSafety form

Tags: android, google-play

The App was rejected due to the reason that the App is getting the user's approximate location whereas in the DataSafety form, I have specified Users Precise location. I then updated the DataSafety form changing the PRECISE LOCATION to Approximate Location and submitted it for review, but again the App was rejected for the same reason.

I made an appeal and there is an appeal confirmation mail with the same reason, something very clueless, the update is essential to my users as it has got an important fix.

Not sure what to do

[image]

[image]

Comment: We have no idea what your problem is.  The only one who can tell you is Google.